# How to find the solutions $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $13x \equiv 1$ mod $15$ and $ x^2 \equiv 9$ mod $100$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I calculated that the first equation is equal to $x \equiv 7$ mod $15$. When solving $x^2 \equiv 9$ mod $100$, i found $x \equiv \pm 3$ mod $100$ and $x\equiv \pm 47$ mod $100$. But since the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem) says that those modulos have to be co prime, i am stuck. What is the trick from now one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check which of the solutions modulo $100$ agree with the $7$ mod $15$, when reduced to modulo $5$. We get that $3$ and $-47\mod{100}$ does not fit with $7\mod 15$, and they must be discarded. You're now left with $-3$ or $47\mod 100$.

Now, since they both agree modulo $5$, you can throw away that particular piece of information from the modulo $15$ equation without losing any valuable information (we still keep that information in the $x \equiv -3\text{ or }47\mod{100}$ part of the system). Which is to say, you may reduce it to $7\equiv1 \mod3$. This puts us into CRT territory, and you get two different solutions modulo $300$.
$$
x \equiv \cases{1\mod3\\-3\text{ or }47\mod{100}}\implies x \equiv 97 \text{ or }247 \mod{300}
$$